# Counting multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a large multidimensional array, which is output into an HTML table. Each second-level array has the same number of values. I need to count how many of the key/value pairs in the first array, which is [247326] in this example. Is there a way to do it without looping through?

```
Array
(
    [247326] => Array
        (
            [144784] => 0
            [144785] => 0
            [144787] => 1
            [144815] => 0
            ...
            [144909] => 0
        )

    [247327] => Array
        (
            [144784] => 0
            [144785] => 0
            [144787] => 1
            [144788] => 0
            ...
            [144909] => 0
        )

    [247328] => Array
        (
            [144784] => 0
            [144785] => 0
            [144787] => 1
            [144788] => 0
            ...
            [144789] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Use the function count [ for example count($array[247326]);  count(current($array)); ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of them are the same size, you can just call the last one and check it's size:

`count(end($arr));`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your array is called `$array` then you can get the number of key/value pairs in items 247326 with:

```
$pairs = count($array[247326]);
```

The result will be in `$pairs`. It you don't know the first item in the array you can get it with `reset()` like so:

```
$first = reset($array);
$pairs = count($first);
```

This is so simple that I must have misunderstood your question?